# Changing real Array of byte Java

Tags: java, reference, call

I have that:

```
      byte[] AllNumber = {4,3,2,1,0,5,6,7,8,9};
      byte[] MultNumber = {4,3,2,1,0,5,6,7,8,9}; // No matter the content
      byte[] DivNumber = {4,3,2,1,0,5,6,7,8,9}; // No matter the content

      Alter(AllNumber,MultNumber,DivNumber,5.0,3,2); //The Arrays must be Altered!!

      for (int i = 0; i<MultNumber.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("MultNumber["+i+"]:"+MultNumber[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i<DivNumber.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("DivNumber["+i+"]:"+DivNumber[i]);
      }
```

Now I have this method:

```
      Alter(byte[] src, byte[] Mlt, byte[] Dvs, double dNum, int Lngt, int Ini) {
        // INI THE PROBLEM
        Mlt = Arrays.copyOf(Mlt, src.length + Lngt);  //HERE IS THE ASSIGNATION
        for (int i = ini; i<Mlt.length; i++) {
          Mlt[i] = Mlt[i]*dNum; //No matter the operation (to simplify the problem)
        }

        Dvs = Arrays.copyOf(Dvs, src.length - Lngt);  //HERE IS THE ASSIGNATION
        for (int i = Ini; i<Dvs.length; i++) {
          Dvs[i] = Dvs[i]/dNum; //No matter the operation (to simplify the problem)
        }
        // END THE PROBLEM
      }
```

Another Attempt

```
      //Another Attempt!!! 
      Alter(byte[] src, byte[] Mlt, byte[] Dvs, double dNum, int Lngt, int Ini) {
        // INI THE PROBLEM
        byte[] TM = new byte[src.length + Lngt]
        for (int i = ini; i<Mlt.length; i++) {
          TM[i] = Mlt[i]*dNum; //No matter the operation (to simplify the problem)
        }
        Mlt = TM;  //HERE IS THE ASSIGNATION
        TM = null;

        byte[] TD = new byte[src.length - Lngt]
        for (int i = Ini; i<Dvs.length; i++) {
          TD[i] = Dvs[i]/dNum; //No matter the operation (to simplify the problem)
        }
        Dvs = TD;  //HERE IS THE ASSIGNATION
        TD = null;
        // END THE PROBLEM
      }
```

I want to get two arrangements changed after performing the call of method "Alter".
How I can do it this?

I need to change the length of Arrays!

Thank you for your valuable help.

PD. It seems later to make the assignations to the arrays, the "Call by Reference" is converted in "Call by Value". If THE ASSIGNATION is omitted the "Call by Reference" follows being.

Comment: What you are really trying to do is create a new version of your source array, representing a 'mutation' operation of some sort. So, create the new array in your method and ***return*** it. Then you can either assign it to the same variable that was holding your source data, or even better, to a different one with a more meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to change the length of Arrays!

That is not possible in Java. You could use a dynamic data structure, such as the implementations of the `java.util.List` interface.

Your assignment doesnt help, as the method parameters are local variables, referencing the original objects. So your object has two references, and you only change the reference known inside your method.

Java uses call by value, and for reference data types the value is the value of the reference (so you get a reference to the same object).

You could do something like this, when you want to change an array.

```
public static int[] arrayTwiceAsBig(int[] original) {
    int[] newOne = new int[original.length * 2);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, newOne, 0, original.length);
    return newOne;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3};
myArray = arrayTwiceAsBig(myArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```